# Changing boolean value from another servlet to stop the loop

Tags: java, for-loop, servlets, interrupt, boolean-logic

I have a for loop which runs based on value of boolean variable.

```
public class LoopClass{
..
private boolean[] toInterrupt = new boolean[];
public boolean getValue() {
        
        return toInterrupt[0];
    }

    public void setValue(boolean newValue) {
        toInterrupt[0] = newValue;
    }
}
public method abc{

for loop{

if (getValue()){
   break:
}}}
```

I want to interrupt this loop through servlet:

```
public class interruptServlet exetnds HttpServlet {

LoopClass = lp = new LoopClass();
lp.setValue(true)
}
```

Even after executing servlet, boolean toInterrupt[0] always remain false.
How can i change boolean value through servlet to stop the loop ?

Comment: If `interruptServlet` is running in another thread (as I assume it is), you need to properly manage the _multi-threaded_ access to the variable to avoid data consistency issues. BTW, please, post the code as close as possible to what you're actually doing, so volunteers can help you better; the one you posted doesn't compile.

Comment: If you create a new instance of `LoopClass`, it won’t affect the value in some other existing instance.

Comment: @TimMoore: Thanks for your comment. how can i change the value in existing instance ?

Comment: You need a reference to that instance. I think the question would benefit from a lot more context about what your use case is overall.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, the new `LoopClass` instance does not share any state with the actual servlet.

There is a pretty easy way to share state between servlets: the `ServletContext`. For instance:

**LoopClass**:

```
private static final String INTERRUPTED_ATTRIBUTE = LoopClass.class.getName() + ".interrupted";

public static void setInterrupt(ServletContext context, boolean interrupt) {
    context.setAttribute(INTERRUPTED_ATTRIBUTE, interrupt);
}

private boolean interrupted() {
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(getServletContext().getAttribute(INTERRUPTED_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

**InterruptServlet**:

```
LoopClass.setInterrupt(getServletContext(), true);
```

Note that I kept all of the actual code for interrupting in `LoopClass`. That way you can easily rename the attribute name without having to change other code.

Comment: You're welcome.